# Passing JavaScript variable to createURL - YII Framework

Tags: yii

I am trying to pass javascript variable to Controller action by calling "CreateURL" function,

JS Code:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('searchaevg', "
$('#newAddval_btn').click(function(){
var r = document.getElementById('cid').value;    
    window.location = '". yii::app()->createUrl('baseContact/add_refvalue',array("id" => ("#r"))). "'; });

");
```

Above code is not calling controller action, it throws

```
error "Error 400
Your request is invalid."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

> window.location = '".
>   yii::app()->createUrl('baseContact/add_refvalue'). "/id/'+r